# I need to edit the z-index overlay in woo slider

Tags: woocommerce-theming

I'm using woocommerce storefront theme and want to edit the woo-slider overlay to a gradient instead of a black box. I also want to style the text overlay and add some padding. Does anyone know how I can do this?
Here's a link to the page in question: https://olivetreemortuary.biz